# Starting Tezos node gives "Bus error: 10"

Tags: node, bootstrapping

```
>./tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 --connections 10 
Feb 10 20:56:31 - node.main: Starting the Tezos node...
Feb 10 20:56:31 - node.main: Peer's global id: idqebupXmLLYzWb7tZ1eefRxQxUMTW
Feb 10 20:56:31 - node.worker: bootstrapping chain...
Bus error: 10
```

Only thing that has changed is I installed go 1.11.5

Comment: deleted .tezos-node . However I cannot connect to peers. Can't remember or find in the docs the file where to keep peer info and also the format. For Example 34.255.45.216:9732 ... do I need to specify the port ?

Comment: Did you stop your node without sending first an INT signal ? It might happen, in very rare occasion, that LMDB would not properly close the database, and a Bug Error can happen when it tries to read the database at a wrong position.

Comment: Lost power . So what you explain may be the cause. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up deleting `~/.tezos-node` directory.

I regenerated `config.json` but had to add peers:

```
{ "p2p": { "listen-addr": "[::]:9732" } }
{ "rpc": { "listen-addr": "127.0.0.1:8732" },
  "p2p": {
    "bootstrap-peers": [
      "34.255.45.216:9732",
      "176.9.31.115:9732",
      "80.127.110.188:9732",
      "77.109.165.235:9732",
      "34.255.45.216",
      "176.9.23.88:9732",
      "139.162.162.254:9732",
      "136.144.212.170:9732",
      "217.182.198.183:9732",
      "34.252.42.102:9732",
      "52.28.53.250:9732",
      "130.113.162.70:9732",
      "118.27.37.134:9732",
      "40.67.217.107:9732",
      "178.238.239.10:9732",
      "52.47.159.76:9732",
      "34.207.244.83:9732",
      "86.229.36.194:9732",
      "188.134.8.225:9732",
      "188.134.8.225:9732"
    ],

    "listen-addr": "[::]:9732" }
  }
```

The chain is now syncing.

It seems like the data inside of `~/.tezos-node` was somehow corrupted.

Comment: Do you trust all these nodes you added? All nodes you enter in bootstrap-peers are marked by the node as trusted. Probably it is a better idea to just enter boot.tzbeta.net as the only trusted node. Your node will then connect to around 5 nodes in an area closest to yours. These are all run by the Tezos Foundation. After your node is bootstrapped, it will automatically find other nodes, which do not need to be trusted.

Comment: Didn’t do that but will do. How do I specify , do I need the ip ?